# Linux environmental variable

Tags: linux, path, environment-variables, tcsh

I have two users in a linux box. user_1 has the executables in the /bin folder whereas user_2 does not. I wanted to use that executable from user_2 so I set my environmental variable PATH directed to the user_2. When I execute from the command line, I get errors,

```
node: Command not found.
```

When I login as user_1, I can execute the file so it seems like either PATH is not set correctly or there is other way of executing. I set to ~/.tcshrc and did

```
source ~/.tcshrc
```

Any good comments with explanation of how environment variable directs between users would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but about configuration of the tcsh shell. http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.com would be a better site for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the privilege to execute the executable files of user_1. Ask user_1 or the the administrator to grant you the privilege.

Do a search for chmod may give you a solution.